# Booting multiple operating systems, does install order matter?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, windows-7, macosx

I'm moving my computer from a dual boot (Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04) to a triple boot (Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04, Mac OS X 10.9). I currently use Grub to start up my computer into either Windows or Ubuntu. I've done dual boot installs about 5 times on 2 different machines in the past, but I've never had the booting work through Grub. Normally I have to use Windows' boot menu. I'm not sure, but I think it had something to do with the order I installed the OS' in (Windows, then Ubuntu).

So essentially, what order should I install my operating systems in in order to use Grub as my boot menu? The partitioning is Windows 7 on a 128GB ssd by itself, and another 128GB ssd drive split between Ubuntu and Mac. I know this is a Ubuntu-based Q&A board (didn't know where else to put it) so what I'm looking for is information on what Ubuntu does to the boot process when it is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose whatever order you like.

`grub` will install at the same time as Ubuntu, but even if you rewrite another bootloader on top of it, you can always reinstall `grub` from a live-usb.

So, if you decide NOT to install Ubuntu the last, the easiest way to reinstall your `grub`, is :

- boot a live distribution (usb, dvd, ...)
- get an internet connexion
- type in a console :

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
  ```

---

Boot-repair is a pretty useful GUI tool to "repair" the bootloader (in this case, install `grub`). 
[image: boot-repair]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install Ubuntu after installing other OS beacause it will detect correctly OS that has been already installed on your computer.

However, just like Mr-Vaykadji said, you can reinstall grub with a live device if you have one.